# Bold/italic text not shown (hidden) in PDF generated with Cpdf (aka Cezpdf or R&O's PDF Creation)

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

Bold and italic text is not shown in the generated PDF.

```
$pdf = new Cezpdf(); 
$pdf->addText(65,675,10, '<b>Hidden</b> Shown');
// Doing more stuff to the PDF ...
$pdf->output();
```

The bold word "Hidden" is not displayed in the output.
The regular word "Shown" is displayed in the output.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be because the underlying Cpdf class handles text differentily, depending on the presence of a control directive like "b" or not.

Replace the lines 2908 and 2909 in Cpdf.php:

```
$this->addContent(' /F'.$this->currentFontNum.' '.sprintf('%.1f',$size).' Tf ');
$this->addContent(' ('.$this->filterText($part, false).') Tj');
```

With the following three lines:

```
$place_text = $this->filterText($part, false);
$this->addContent(" /F$this->currentFontNum ".sprintf('%.1F Tf ', $size));
$this->addContent(" [($place_text)] TJ");
```

Now the text inside a control directive is shown.